# Trying to remove "/" from MySql result string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select

So i tried REPLACE (), TRIM() and else, but i dont know how to remove first character from my sql Query, when that character is '/'.

Query im using is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(SUBSTR(TRENN,-11,10)) AS PN 
FROM table 
WHERE NR_VP_EXTERN IS NOT NULL 
  and LENGTH(TRIM(SUBSTR(TRENN,-11,10))) > 3;
```

And i'm getting results like "0005664686" and "/46464866486"

So my question is how do i modify that query to remove '/' from the start of string where '/' is ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `SUBSTR(TRENN,-11,10)` <-- what is this supposed to be doing?

Comment: Examples of trenn please.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan op wants to remove the first one, not any one

Comment: You use `TRIM()` - this means that spaces may be both leading and trailing. If so - where does the problematic slash char may occur? `'   /123   '`? `'/   123  '`? `'   /   123   '`? any of above? Show **ALL** possible patterns of possible `TRENN` values - maybe `TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(trenn, '/', -1))` will be the best solution...

Comment: @Tom, please could you add a bit of information to this question to help us answer it. In particular, it would help if we could see a sample of the data with an example of the content in TRENN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use [string function `trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) for this. It seems like you want:

```
trim(leading '/' from trenn)
```

The purpose of `substr()` in your original query is rather unclear, so I left it apart. You can add it back as needed.

Comment: The substring is there because without it i get result like "5453#2      /4525546464" and i want only ending number without '/'

Comment: What actual output do you want from `5453#2 /4525546464` ?

Comment: I only want number 4525546464, but not all numbers is 10 characters long so where string is 9 characters long, there comes unwanted '/'   so result then is   '/4525546464' and i want to remove that '/' when it comes with result so i have only number

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but if your input be `5453#2 /4525546464` and you only want to capture the final collection of digits, and you are using MySQL 8+, then `REGEXP_SUBSTR` might be the easiest way here:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('5453#2 /4525546464', '[0-9]+$')
FROM dual;
```

This returns `4525546464` based on the input.